# Error when using insert statement through SqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to send an insert statement but its throwing an error on my connection string.
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=***.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=***;user id=***;database=***;allowuservariables=True;password=***;persistsecurityinfo=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Member(FName,LName,PhoneNumber,Email,MemberType) 
                        VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4,@param5)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", txtFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", txtLastName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", txtPhoneNum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", txtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", cboMemType.Text);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you are inserting in mysql database, then you can't use `SqlCommand`.

Comment: I'm new to this, why not and what should I be using?

Comment: What is your database server? is it MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: @Damith It's is mysql I believe

Comment: You can use MySql connector for .NET. Download it from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ and  read how to use it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html